# My files system storage showing wrong data

Tags: filesystem, filemanager

My file system is showing like this:

[image]

there the third row: /home is showing that I used 18.4EB, where it should be more like 18.4GB.

It is showing correctly in gparted, problem is with system-monitor.

Comment: Output of `df -h | grep nvm` would be useful.

Comment: 18.4Exabytes would exceed what most terrestrial file systems can allocate. This looks very much like a bug, and it would be great if you could [report it on LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor) so that someone can take a look at it 